# AWS EMR network connection

Tags: amazon-emr

I am trying to install a package into EMR cluster. Every time I get the following error

WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f5af4e9dad0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable')': /simple/fastparquet/

What should i do?

I tried to ping into google.com but same problem persisits.

Comment: Which interface are you working on - EMR Studio? Submit a step to EMR on EC2?

Comment: I am working with EMR

Comment: Are you working with Jupyter notebook (interactive) or submitting a job to an EMR cluster (batch)?

Comment: I am using PySpark i jupyter notebook

Answer (score 1):

To interact using PySpark in a Jupyter notebook environment, consider using [EMR Studio](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-studio.html) (not EMR notebook). It requires some foundation [setup work](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-studio-set-up.html).

Afterwards, you can install libraries on the notebook level.

Listing current libraries:

```
sc.list_packages()
```

Installing the Celery (for example) library

```
sc.install_pypi_package("celery")
```

Ref: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-managed-notebooks-installing-libraries-and-kernels.html#emr-managed-notebooks-work-with-libraries